# C# Console: Read number input and associate it with string

Tags: c#

I would like to make a sort of menu, where you can choose a dish, you enter the number of the dish and it will add the dish to your list.

This is like a simple version of it, but

```
Console.WriteLine("CHINESE");
Console.Write("Type in the number of the dish you want: ");
int id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

if (id == 35)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Pizza Funghi is added to your list.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{id} is not available.");
}

// I would like to use something like this instead of multiple if's
//35 = pizza funghi
//01 = pasta bolognese
//02 = pasta napolitana
//36 = pizza carbonara

Console.ReadKey();
```

Could you guys give me some tips, should I use a list, a dictionary or an array? or should I use classes?

Thanks!

Comment: A `Dictionary<int, string>` would make sense here since each item is unique

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If not why haven't you tried out using a list, dictionary or array - try using each, see what works best for you. You will find you get the best responses on SO if you show you have put in some effort - if what you have tried doesn't work then post a specific question about that problem. If you want to ask if you can improve what you are doing then SO is not the right site - [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Dictionary<int, string>` if each item occurs only once.

Make a dictionary to hold your menu:

```
var menu = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    { 35, "Pizza Funghi" },
    { 1, "Pasta Bolognese" },
    { 2, "Pizza Napolitana" },
    { 36, "Pizza Carbonara" }
};
```

Then your code looks like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("CHINESE");
Console.Write("Type in the number of the dish you want: ");
int id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

if (menu.ContainsKey(id))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{menu[id]} is added to your list.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{id} is not available.");
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: And have a look at [link to int.TryParse(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) (or use try ... catch) to stump ppl trying to order your dish verbatim (i.e. typing WanTans as Input ;)

Comment: As @PatrickArtner quite rightly points out there are some improvements that can be made to the code. `TryParse` will prevent incorrect input, you might want to look at looping until correct input has been received, and as Sefe says in his answer a class may be more appropriate if you want other properties such as price, but that's more fitting for CodeReview ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary with a `Dish` class as the type for the values. That allows you to associate more than just a name for the dish (I assume you don't juist wan to output the name, but do some further actions with your selection:

```
class Dish {
    string Name { get; set; }
    //Additional properties and/or methods would go here
}

//...

Dictionary<int, Dish> dishes = new Dictionary<int, Dish> {
    { 1, new Dish { Name = "Pasta Bolognese" } },
    { 2, new Dish { Name = "Pizza Napolitana" } },
    { 35, new Dish { Name = "Pizza Funghi" } },
    { 36, new Dish { Name = "Pizza Carbonara" } }
}

int id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

//...

bool hasDish = dishes.TryGet( id, out Dish selectedDish);

if (hasDish)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{selectedDish.Name} is added to your list.");
    //You can extend your Dish class with further properties and methods and use them here
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{id} is not available.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would introduce a `Dish` class, it can hold additional properties like the price. Then use a dictionary with the Dish ID as key to retrieve them. Also, this class can easily be converted to an Entity Framework entity if you want to store the dishes in a database.

**Edit**

Run dish selection in a loop - this allows to select multiple dishes.

As suggested by Patrick Artner, fail gracefully if user does not enter a number.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {

        var dishes = new List<Dish> {
            new Dish{ Id = 35, Name = "Pizza Funghi", Price = 11 },
            new Dish{ Id = 01, Name = "Pasta Bolognese", Price = 10 },
            new Dish{ Id = 02, Name = "Pasta Napolitana", Price = 9.5M },
            new Dish{ Id = 36, Name = "Pizza Carbonara", Price = 8 }
        };
        var dishesDict = dishes.ToDictionary(d => d.Id);

        var selectedDishes = new List<Dish>();

        Console.Write("Type in the number of the dish you want or x to stop: ");
        do {
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (input.ToLowerInvariant().Trim() == "x") {
                break;
            }

            int id;
            if (!int.TryParse(input, out id)) {
                Console.WriteLine("Your input must be a number or 'x', please try again!");
                continue;
            }

            if (dishesDict.ContainsKey(id)) {
                var dish  = dishesDict[id];
                selectedDishes.Add(dish);
                Console.WriteLine(dish.Name + " is added to your list.");
            }
            else {  
                Console.WriteLine( id + " is not available.");
            }
        } while (true);

        // Example how to use additional property
        var totalPrice = selectedDishes.Sum(d => d.Price);
        Console.WriteLine("Total Price of selected dishes: " + totalPrice);
    }
}

public class Dish {

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // Example of additional property
    public decimal Price {get; set;}
}
```

[C# Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SLoUGB)